# Set div margin-top to screen height (within iframe, cross browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set `div margin-top` to a `100%` of screen height, however since it's within `iframe` - jQuery doesn't work (returns 0 or inaccurate value).

Using CSS3's `100vh` is an option, but is not supported in some older and mobile browsers.

Is there another solution?

edit:

Forgot to mention - I can only use JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

edit2:

Here's a demo [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LifpG)

edit3:

While I was testing my code on CodePen - turns out that I can get the screen height with JQuery. So where's the problem?

First of all I have to mention that I'm using this code on Tumblr, so it must be a Tumblr specific problem. For the ones unfamiliar with their customization page it looks like this

[image]

For some unknown to me reason, whenever I try to get something browser related from the user using Jquery it always gets that information from the "Actual Page" and not from the preview (iFrame) on the right. That's some faulty design right there. Why? Because on the actual blog page everything works fine.

Here's the workaround I found which currently works, though I'm not exactly sure why.

I serve JQuery to the final product (the actual blog page) using $(document).ready - this wont and does not work on the customize page. However, if I wrap that same code in $(window).resize and serve it only on the customize page it works there as well.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: what about using absolute position? show your markup html to illustrate the question.

Comment: I've added a demo, for some reason a JQuery solution will work on CodePen, but wont work where the final code would go (Tumblr).

Answer (score 0):

How about CSS in `iframe`'s HTML file as:

```
html, 
body {
   height: 100%;
}
div {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
.bellow-cover {
  margin-top: 17%;
}
```

Tried in codepen and it was working fine. Will still look for better solutions though. Do let me know if this is the thing that is required.